# File system errors on virtual machine: Resize inode not valid. fsck exited with status code 4

Tags: virtualbox, filesystem, lvm, ext4, luks

TL;DR

I'm trying to fix a disk that got corrupted because I hard-shutdown the VM. The farthest I've managed to go is to use `fsck.ext4` and a back up superblock to allow me to mount the disk again. When done, I can see system files, but no `/home` folder. I wonder if that is caused because that folder is encrypted and that makes it harder to recover.

---

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04 as a guest OS with VirtualBox 5.2.14. Yesterday I turned the VM off and when I tried to turn it on again I got the `initramfs` console, after typing `exit` I got:

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)

(initramfs) exit

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: Resize inode not valid.

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck
```

### initramfs fsck -y

So, I went ahead and tried:

```
fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
```

Seems like the "disk" got even more messed up with `fskc -y`.

```
...
Free inodes count wrong for group #160 (1334, counted=479). Fix? yes
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 151456/1790544 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 1416234/7161856 blocks
```

Exiting `initramfs` returns:

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

After that executing `reboot` results in:

```
CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu
Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
...
end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000100
```

The good thing is that I made a clone of the virtual machine, so nothing is "lost" (yet :p).

### Live CD

I started the virtual machine with a live CD and when I try to mount the disk from Nautilus (the files manager) I get a pop up with some numbers that says:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "...": Error when getting information for File "/media/ubuntu/.../dev": Structure needs cleaning

#### e2fsck -n

On a new VM clone, executing `e2fsck -n` shows:

```
Inode 392498 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? no

Inode 392499 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 392499 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 392499 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 392499 has imagic flag set.  Clear? no

Inode 392499 has a extra size (50685) which is invalid
Fix? no

Error while iterating over blocks in inode 392499: Cannot iterate data blocks of an inode containing inline data

/dev/dm-1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

Partial log: https://pastebin.com/5HBTe9KL (the complete log was 350k lines long)

#### mkfs.ext4

On a new VM clone:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -S /dev/dm-1
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/dm-1 contains a ext4 file system
    last mounted on / on Sun Jul 22 16:59:28 2018
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 7161856 4k blocks and 1790544 inodes
Filesystem UUID: f1c6b504-984a-4a14-980e-c70bd309ec8a
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done                            
/dev/dm-1 may be further corrupted by superblock rewrite
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Skipping journal creation in super-only mode
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Then I tried to mount the disk through Nautilus and got the pop up:

```
Unable to access location
Error mounting /dev/dm-1 at /media/ubuntu/...: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning
```

#### fsck.ext4

Got a list of backup superblocks:

```
# first one
Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32772
  ...
Backup superblock at 4096000, Group descriptors at 4096001-4096004
# last one
```

Then I tried to use the backup blocks. Each attempt on a new clone of the VM.

```
fsck.ext4 -b 32768 /dev/dm-1 # in new vm
fsck.ext4 -b 4096000 /dev/dm-1 # in new vm
```

In both cases the result was the I was able to mount the drive! And it seemed to have most of the system files (`/bin`, `/etc`, `/opt`, etc.) Unfortunately, there is no `/home` folder.

The `/home` folder is encrypted, but even before I start any of the debug/recovery steps above I always have to decrypt it first. However, now I'm wondering if that is getting in the way of a successful `fsck.ext4`.

Comment: Click the `x` on the window border and then select `Power off the machine`.

Comment: Ha! I thought that was what it meant to use the option "shutdown signal", because of the lighting/power icon...